# c program - How to return the k-th character when the reverse of the string S is repeated infinite number of times?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to code for the question :
define the function getCharacter which accepts a string S and an integer K as input. the function must return K-th character when the reverse of the string S is repeated infinite number of times.

I try this Many times..But I couldn't get the output..I'm beginner to C..My code is here..

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>
char getCharacter(char *s,int k)
{
    char rev[100];
    int b,e,c=0;
    while(s[c]!='\0')
    {
       c++;
    }
    e=c-1;
    for(b=0;b<c;b++)
    {
        rev[b]=s[e];
        e--;
    }
    rev[b]='\0';
    char res;
    res=rev[k+1];
    return res;
}
int main()
{    
    char s[100],f;
    int k;
    gets(s);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    f=getCharacter(s,k);
    printf("%c",f);
    return 0;    
}
```

### Required Output :

INPUT :
skillrack
13
OUTPUT:
r

Comment: `gets` is dangerous and obsolete. Read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and use `fgets`. Infinity do not exist in real computers. So you need to *think* and do some math - [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) with a pencil

Comment: What does "reverse of the string" mean, especially in conjunction with the "infinite times" part?

Comment: If allowed, use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get all warnings and debug info; then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable. Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Take inspiration from the source code of *existing* open source programs (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)....) and read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or newer

Comment: But **StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website**. Use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) - which is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), so you can download it and study its source code- to edit your C code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sir..It's Not my Homework..Due to My self interest to learn C , I try this code in that website..But I'm totally confused in this reverse string infinite times concept..so that I post my question sir..Thanks for your reply sir.

Comment: Infinity and real computer don't mix well. [infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity) is a mathematical concept. On real computers, data is finite (e.g. an `int` has 32 bits)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since this appears to be a homework/practice question, there's going to be no code but here are some pointers based on your question:

1st requirement is to reverse the string followed by infinite repetitions. Now, since computers are limited resources of memory/storage, storing an infinite string is out of the question, so one needs to improvise.

Note that the reverse of a string `abcd` can be printed to the console by just printing the string beginning from the end starting with `d` in this case and then moving the index backward, so that's `d`, `c`, `b` and `a`. Unless one doesn't need to store the reversed string, that's a good enough method to just obtain the reverse.

The next thing to note is that if one places the string `dcba` and joins another *copy* of this reversed string, it becomes `dcbadcba`. Now if one needs to access the `0`th character of this reversed string, it's `d` but so is the `4`th character, which is `d` too. Figure out why that is. (Hint: **look** at the original string and find how `4` is related to it). So, once this is established, one can figure out that the infinite reverse of the string actually doesn't need to be *copied* (or *joined*) from the original string at all but can be just obtained by manipulating the index. This should give enough pointers to solve the question.

Also, since you'll require it, this is a link to [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: @kiruthikaparamaguru Good. One suggestion. Don't assume all are `sir`s here. There are a lot of `madam`s too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your Reply..
I done my code successfully..
here is my code..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char getCharacter(char *s,int k)
{
    char rev[100],rev1[1000];
    int b,e,c=0,len,n=100;
    len=strlen(s);
    while(s[c]!='\0')
    {
        c++;
    }
    e=c-1;
    for(b=0;b<c;b++)
    {
        rev[b]=s[e];
        e--;
    }
    rev[b]='\0';
    char *result;
    result = malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
    while (n--)
    {
        strcat(result,rev);
    }
    char res;
    res=result[k-1];
    return res;
}
int main()
{    
    char s[100],f;
    int k;
    gets(s);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    f=getCharacter(s,k);
    printf("%c",f);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: That solution has so many extraneous elements. You don't need `rev`, `rev1`, call to `malloc`....nothing at all. You just need the construct to obtain the user input, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
char getCharacter(char *s,int k)
{
  int len = strlen(s);
  if (k % len == 0) return s[0];
  if (k < len) return s[len-k];
  return (s[len - 1 - (k % len) + 1]);
}
```